# Convert string to list of Fractions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to convert strings of the form

```
'[[2, 3.1], [4/5, 5/6]]'
```

to a 2d list of Fraction objects from the fractions module.  In the particular case given above, the result should be

```
[[Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(31, 10)], [Fraction(4, 5), Fraction(5, 6)]]
```

The spacing in the string won't necessarily be as uniform as I've written it (no spaces, extra spaces, uneven numbers of spaces, etc).

I can do this in several steps by peeling off the outer brackets, splitting the string at the `']'`s, removing empty strings from the resulting list, removing any nondigit from the beginning of each string in the list in a while loop, splitting each of those strings at the comma, and finally converting the elements of the nested lists to Fractions.

But that's fairly cumbersome.  Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Parse to an AST and replace the inner elements with the appropriate calls.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  The docs page for the ast module is a bit over my head.

Comment: AST is a `built-in` with python `import ast`  `ast.literal_eval(input)`

Comment: @iam.Carrot: In this case, I think you'd want `ast.parse`, so you can get the actual AST tree to modify before passing it to `eval`. Doing a `literal_eval` immediately converts the `3.1`, `4/5` and `5/6` values to floats, which loses some precision.

Comment: @Blckknght: Do you know how to do this and could provide an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to transform the numeric literals in your string into calls to `Fraction`. After the transformation, you can call `eval` on the result to get the appropriately nested list.

You don't need to handle the division operations in a special way, since they will work exactly as you want if we just convert both numerator and denominator into `Fraction` objects (so `4/5` becomes `Fraction("4")/Fraction("5")`, which evaluates to `Fraction(4, 5)`).

The transformation should put quotation marks around the numbers you pass to `Fraction`, as that prevents `eval` from parsing numbers with decimal points into `float` instances (which usually causes a loss of precision). `Fraction` can do the parsing instead, from a string, and it won't lose any precision since all finite-length decimal numbers have an exact `Fraction` representation.

Code:

```
import re
from fractions import Fraction

input_text = '[[2, 3.1], [4/5, 5/6]]'

transformed_text = re.sub(r'([\d.]+)', r'Fraction("\1")', input_text)

results = eval(transformed_text)
print(results) # [[Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(31, 10)], [Fraction(4, 5), Fraction(5, 6)]]
```

Comment: Regex is fragile, e.g. it does not cover signs and scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a nifty code snippet that can help you out with it:

```
from fractions import Fraction
input_string = '[[2, 3.1], [4/5, 5/6]]'
parsed_input = [item for item in ''.join((char if char in '0123456789./' else '-') for char in input_string).split('-') if item]
output_array = [Fraction(i).limit_denominator(10) for i in parsed_input]
```

I hope this helps. Please use the comments section incase of any ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast
import re
from fractions import Fraction

input_text = '[[2, 3.1], [1e100, -5/6]]'

transformed_text = ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'([^,\[\]\s]+)', r'"\1"', input_text))
transformed_text =  [[ Fraction(j) for j in i]  for i in transformed_text ]
```

- regex is simpler: `Fraction(...)` can handle many different input forms; see here https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction with the note
  that since version 3.2 the `Fraction` constructor now accepts `float` and `decimal.Decimal instances`.
- `ast.literal_eval` not `eval`